# Python, Flask, SQLAlchemy 500 error with no error message

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a class in my model setup like this:

```
User(db.Model):
    properties = db.relationship(
    'Property', backref='user', lazy='joined')
```

where Property is it's own class, with a foreign key referencing the User table. When I try to access this data like so (I'm omitting a lot of needless code so bear with me):

```
users = User.query.all()
return {
    'users': [{
        'properties': user.properties
    } for user in users]
}
```

My console just says:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Oct/2017 10:46:08] "GET /api/auth/me HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Oct/2017 10:46:09] "GET /api/user/users?page=0&size=25&multiproperty=false&qs=&qc= HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1997, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 273, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 273, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 273, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 273, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 273, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 161, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1542, in handle_exception
    raise e
AssertionError
```

No actual error message telling me what is wrong. If my understanding is correct, then user.properties is an array (or list I guess) of objects, each one representing a row in the Property table associated with that user. When I print user.properties this is sort of what I see

```
[<app.models.Property object at 0x7f94a1805ed0>, <app.models.Property object at 0x7f94a1805fd0>]
```

And I can access the individual properties of each object, such as address, city, state, etc. But when I try to pass that specific information I get a 500 error with no useful message, so I have no idea why that isn't valid or what I need to do to fix it. I've combed through the Flask SQLAlchemy docs but they are sparse and I can't find anything else online to help because I don't really have anything to google.

It's clear that I'm misunderstanding something here so I'm hoping someone familiar in these technologies can help me clear this up.

Comment: Try to change `User.query.all()` to `db.session.query(User).all()`.

Comment: hm, that worked but why did it work?

Comment: It might be some problem with flask-restful and the way how classes handle session object, but I don't use it at all so only have heard of such problem and solution.